# QML/QtQuick - Images overwritten in ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When I put several images in a ColumnLayout, they overwrite themselves and I see only the last one.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
Rectangle{
    width: parent.width
    color: "#00ffffff"
    height: 370
    ColumnLayout{
        width : parent.width
        spacing : 0
        Image {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            source: "img/img1.png"
        }
        Image {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            source: "img/img2.png"
     }
        Image {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            source: "img/img3.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on how I can manage to see the 3 images one below the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are forcing the image to be centered vertically and horizontally when doing this:

```
Image {
  anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
  anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
  source: "img/img3.png"
}
```

If you want your images to be centered horizontally but at the same time keep the layout in the column you should remove the `anchors.verticalCenter` property from your `Image` components

Comment: Thank you !That was it.
I removed the "anchors.verticalCenter" property from my Images components and I put it in the ColumnLayout above, and that did the trick.
Thanks.